# How to correctly use pointers to compute average

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I want to use avgs as a pointer, but how would I modify the code below to use it correctly? I am computing the average of an int array, given the starting pointer and the length..

```
int compute_average(int *avgs, int len) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  sum += avgs[i];
  return (int)(sum / len);
}
```

I tried writing it like this, but it didn't work correctly:

```
  do {sum += *avgs;} 
  while(*(avgs++)!='\0');
```

Comment: What is wrong? The first snippet looks fine to me. Up to a possible overflow. The second makes a little sense, as your `avgs` is not a string, so checking for null-termination is meaningless.

Comment: I'm using the average to calculate, if the input from sound module is high or low. When I tried writing it with pointers, it generates all sound as high. :( Without my bit of code it works perfectly fine..

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. The first code is correct, but might produce an overflow in `sum`. Maybe that is what you observe? Try defining `sum` as larger integer type.

Comment: You perform integer division the result will be int even without you casting it to int, and it won’t be average. Say you have {1,2} array the average is 1.5 but your code will return 1, is this what you want?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Testing that your pointer doesn't point into a `\0` is fine when you work with strings. Here you have an array of ints and a length so you can't really use a destination point to stop incrementing the pointer. You need to use that `len` just like in your first snippet but instead of accessing the `i`th element of your array, you can still increment the pointer. Something like this :

```
int compute_average(int *avgs, int len) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    sum += *(avgs++);
  return (int)(sum / len);
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the OPs first snippet? What problem does it solve?

Comment: It is very similar, isn't it... But somehow this works perfectly, but my try didn't.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I understood correctly, the question was how to make a function work exactly like the first one but using pointer arithmetics to move through the array.